# Having a python output issue, outout is concatonated

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

today = pd.Timestamp('today').floor('D')

f1 = pd.read_csv('/home/user/Desktop/files/Hosts_new_this_Inventory_' + today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.csv')
f2 = pd.read_csv('/home/user/Desktop/files/new_Report_' + today.strftime('%m-%d-%y') + '.csv')

f1f2 = pd.concat([f2,f1], axis=0)
f1f2.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

text_file = open('/home/user/Desktop/files/file_compare_' + today.strftime('%m-%d-%y') + '.txt', "w")
text_file.write(str (f1f2))
text_file.close()
```

The output in the text file is showing concatenated, not sure why

```
         IP       Local_IP
0       0.0.0.1            NaN
1      0.0.0.10            NaN
2      0.0.0.10            NaN
3      0.0.0.10            NaN
4     0.0.0.100            NaN
...         ...            ...
6286        NaN  192.168.1.1
6287        NaN  192.168.1.22
6288        NaN  192.168.1.25
6289        NaN   192.168.1.96
6290        NaN           None

[7802 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Use `axis=1` in `pd.concat`.

Comment: got same output

Comment: This might seem like a dumb question but is there a possibility that there's duplicate indices

Comment: Update, when I outputted this to a csv it worked. Strange